# Heroku not seeing OpenVino when trying to deploy

Tags: heroku, deployment, buildpack, openvino, heroku-api

I have an OpenVino model I'm trying to deploy via Heroku. The app runs on the machine (since OpenVino is installed on the machine in the /opt/intel directory). Even after successfully installing OpenVino with pip, I'd make the import but still get the error message:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/intel/openvino_2021/python/python3.9/openvino/inference_engine/ie_api.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCMethod_New
  Referenced from: /opt/intel/openvino_2021/python/python3.9/openvino/inference_engine/ie_api.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

when trying to import OpenVino in the script. For that reason, I gave up on using pip and instead built OpenVino from source on the machine. The script can run fine with OpenVino on the machine, but the question is how to deploy this to Heroku without including OpenVino in the requirements.txt file generated with pip freeze.

Specifying OpenVino in the requirements.txt for Heroku does not work (not simple to install with pip as explained above), so I tried to move the expected OpenVino folder into the venv folder. In the project folder, I copied the OpenVino folder into venv > lib > python3.9 > sitepackages. However, once deployed to Heroku that seems to have no effect and I still get the following error in the Heroku logs:

```
2022-01-06T19:39:59.115102+00:00 app[web.2]: File "./main.py", line 26, in <module>
2022-01-06T19:39:59.115206+00:00 app[web.2]: from openvino.inference_engine import IECore, IENetwork
2022-01-06T19:39:59.115219+00:00 app[web.2]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openvino/inference_engine/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
2022-01-06T19:39:59.115309+00:00 app[web.2]: from .ie_api import *
2022-01-06T19:39:59.115333+00:00 app[web.2]: ImportError: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So the expected folder is not there. Of course, for Heroku it's also a different directory structure:

```
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
```

Instead of:

```
/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

However I need to get openvino in that site-packages directory for the Heroku app.

How can I manually add the expected openvino folder to /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages? If that's not possible, how can I edit the buildpack to install openvino for the Heroku app?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't try to manually cram things into Python's `site-packages` directory. _Specifically_, what do you mean by "not simple to install with pip"? Please read [ask].

Comment: Specifically, the pip installs simply don't work for openvino (no matching distribution) and I had to build from source.

Comment: Please include the _full_ error message. "Simply don't work" is not enough information, especially since [`openvino` exists on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/openvino/). And 'the "no matching distribution" error' is not sufficiently detailed.

Comment: I see your point, I am trying to consolidate a very long story of trials and errors to just the essential information. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Now that more detail is added, do you have any ideas for troubleshooting the issue? Much appreciated.

Comment: OpenVINO appears to be for Intel hardware only. Is that correct? As far as I know, Heroku provides no guarantees about underlying hardware vendors. Heroku is a platform-as-a-service vendor, and its offering is at a fairly high level of abstraction.

Comment: You still haven't responded to my questions. (a) What is the _complete error message_ you get when Heroku tries to install via `requirements.txt`? That by far the best way to install things on Heroku if it works. (b) Is OpenVINO for Intel hardware only?

Comment: Sorry and thanks for the help. Yes openvino is for intel hardware. I will add full error message shortly

Comment: You said in a comment on your (now deleted) repost that "libpython… is not mentioned once" in this question. In fact, it is: "ImportError: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". [You edited that into this question in your first edit, at about 8pm UTC on January 6](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70612896/2). Thank you for deleting the duplicate. Editing this question to add relevant information is the proper way to have a conversation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you encountered: `ImportError: libpython3.9.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` was due to missing external dependency on Heroku.

Follow the steps below to resolve this issue:

Add a `runtime.txt` to your app’s root directory to specify a Python runtime. Refer to [Selecting a runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#selecting-a-runtime).

```
python-3.8.12
```

Add an `Aptfile` to your app’s root directory to add support for apt-based dependencies during both compile and runtime. Refer to [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt).

```
libpython3.8
```

Comment: I believe OP is trying to copy OpenVINO from their local machine to Heroku. They seem reluctant to install via `pip` or Pipenv for some reason. I've been asking for details on the error messages they receive for 4 days without success.

Comment: These suggestions worked, thank you Intel Support!